# Cool HTML5/CSS3 tables?

Tags: html, jquery, css

There was a code I saw where it showed like 3 products and the product specs in table form, one right next to the other, and when you hover over a product, it kinda popped. It might have been jQuery, as opposed to HTML5 or CSS3 but I'm wondering if anyone knows what I'm talking about, and where I can find this code?

Comment: @Maddy Please provide a link to the example, or a more thorough description of the effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a desired css style for elemet with id, say "popped".

and the script:

```
     $(".product").hover( 
          function () { $(this).attr('id','popped');}
          function () { $(this).attr('id','');}
        );
```

and "product" is a class of your product tabs.

Comment: Ideally, you should probably use `$.addClass()` and `$.removeClass()` instead, or even `$.toggleClass()` rather than changing the `id` of the element.

Comment: You dont really need jquery if all you're doing is adding an id. You might as well define the styles in tr:hover.

Comment: @Robin `tr:hover` wouldn't have as good of support cross-browser. (IE requires a doctype for it to work out of the box, I believe)

Comment: That's true, but he might not care about ie6. Anyways, I don't think he meant "changing the background color" with "popped", so js is probably required.